How to replace handleRequestInternal method in Spring 5?
I am migrating application from Spring 4 to Spring 5.
I got class public class WebRequestViewController extends AbstractController with overriden method
@Override
    protected final ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
        try {
            final WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest(httpRequest);
            final SpringPropertyMessageLookup messageLookup = new SpringPropertyMessageLookup(getApplicationContext(), httpRequest.getLocale(),
                    "comp");

            final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(webRequestHandler.getViewName());

            webRequestHandler.handleWebRequest(webRequest, modelAndView.getModel(), messageLookup);

            return modelAndView;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception for [" + webRequestHandler + "]", e);
        }
    }

Problem is that in Spring 5 handleRequestInternal method was removed.
I added annotation for RequestViewController class:
@Controller
public class RequestViewController {

and it's enough to build and run but where should I put logic for finding ModelAndView?


@Controller
public class RequestViewController {

    private final WebRequestHandler webRequestHandler;

    public RequestViewController(WebRequestHandler webRequestHandler) {
        this.webRequestHandler = webRequestHandler;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/your-endpoint", method = RequestMethod.GET) // Adjust the URL mapping as necessary
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse, Model model) {
        try {
            final WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest(httpRequest);
            final SpringPropertyMessageLookup messageLookup = new SpringPropertyMessageLookup(getApplicationContext(), httpRequest.getLocale(), "comp");

            // Create ModelAndView using the view name from webRequestHandler
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(webRequestHandler.getViewName());

            // Handle the web request
            webRequestHandler.handleWebRequest(webRequest, model, messageLookup);

            return modelAndView;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception for [" + webRequestHandler + "]", e);
        }
    }
}


plus I removed bean creation from spring-servlet.xml. Thanks @Peng
